# clone a select menu using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i have a simple select menus designed by jNice plugin

http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jNice/

i write a simple jquery to clone the select menu and remove cloned menu

```
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

  $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {

    $('<p class="sel-a"><select name="lang[]" id="p_scnt' + i +'" class="lang"><option value="">Select Language</option><option value="slovenski">Slovenski</option></select><a id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo('#LangForm');
    i++;
    return false;
  });
});
```

it work's fine but there is a small problem it doesn't take the same CSS formatting

i tried a lot of things and even after reading the CSS file i found no classes for the select menus its totally done by the jNice plugin .

i need to know if there a solution for this issue

Thank you

Comment: I wonder why is it so hard for people to copy/paste proper indented code...I mean all I did was copy/paste in VIM, select all and press `=`. Done in 5sec!

Comment: You probably need to apply the plugin to the newly created menu (which is not a clone of anything, by the way). Also, `.live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Comment: @MrOBrian sorry i didn't got you ?

Comment: Which part? The new element you are creating is just a new element, you aren't cloning something. If you want to clone something, use `.clone()`. When you create new elements that you want a plugin applied to, call the plugin on the new elements just like you do in the `document.ready` function.

Comment: Also, ids are unique, you can't have multiple elements in the DOM with the same id. And `.size()` is deprecated, you should be using `.length` instead

Answer (score 0):

Find out what the class is of the select menu that the jNice plugin is creating and change:

```
$('<p class="sel-a"><select name="lang[]" id="p_scnt' + i +'" class="lang"><option value="">Select Language</option><option value="slovenski">Slovenski</option></select><a id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo('#LangForm');
```

TO:

```
$("#LangForm").append($(".selectmenuclass").html());
```

this will make an exact duplicate of the jNice created select menu.  You can keep all your other logic the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you might want to do this, but if you have a reference to the select element, you can do:

```
select.parentNode.replaceChild(select.cloneNode(true), select);
```